# jQuery parsing XML to make slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, xml, hover

So I have a very long question for my code. Here are my requirements:

1. Using jQuery
2. XML parsing of images
3. Must be a slide show
4. Opacity on hover and show text in whiter full opacity

With these piece i built this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    a{text-decoration:none; color:#fff;}
    .pics img { border:0;}
    .pics span{display:none;background:#000;position:absolute; height:346px; width:810px;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7F000000', EndColorStr='#7F000000');
    }
    .pics span p.text {color:#fff;padding:160px 0 0 0;filter: alpha(opacity=100); -khtml-opacity: 1.0; -moz-opacity: 1.0; opacity: 1.0;}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "xml/images.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find("image").each(function(n) //finds each image in the xml
              {
                var path = $(this).attr("path");//path to the image from the xml
                var picURL = $(this).attr("picURL");//picture link url
                var picDesc = $(this).attr("picDesc");//pic description
                //this appends the images to the slide show from the xml
                $("#slideshow").append('<a id="'+n+'" href="' + picURL + '"><span class="desc"><p class="text">'+picDesc+'</p></span><img src="' + path + '"/></a>');
                //this is the hover function to show the text 
                $('a:has(span)').hover(function(){if(this.id == '0'){$('span',this).stop().fadeIn();};$('span', this).fadeIn();},function(){$('span', this).stop(true, false).fadeOut();});    
            });
                $('#slideshow').cycle({fx: 'fade'});
                }
              });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow" class="pics"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the XML to go along with it.

```
<imageList timer="4" fadeTime="1.2" newWindow="false" loaderColor="0x333333" loaderAlpha="0" loaderPosition="bottom" allowLinks="true" randomLoad="false">

<image path="images/slide01.jpg" picURL="" picDesc=""/>
<image path="images/slide02.jpg" picURL="/gallery/glamour_neons" picDesc="G L A M O U R"/>
<image path="images/slide03.jpg" picURL="/gallery/time_manny" picDesc="T I M E  M A G A Z I N E "/>
</imageList>
```

So you can see i use jquery cycle for ease of use with images and it makes it easy to change if the clients requests but because of that i have a settimeout to wait for everything to be pushed to the page then start the cycle plugin. A better way to do this would be awesome . also what i seem to need help with is this isnt functioning 100% perfect. I cant quite seem to get the code any cleaner. Any help on clean and perfectly executing code would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use `setTimeout`**, the arbitrary 500 milliseconds are, well, arbitrary, so the cycle plugin is not guaranteed to work.

Why don't you instantiate the plugin at the end of the Ajax `success` handler?